# What Python package can solve the following non-linear mixed integer program?

Tags: library, python, optimization

Since LaTeX does not work on this platform and I can not properly describe my problem without LaTeX, I am going to use a screenshot instead.

[image]

I have looked into scipy optimize and cvxopt but both are not capable of mixed integer programming. I also checked pulp, but as far I am concerned it only manages mixed integer *linear* programming, but here is my problem: the part where the trace needs to be equal to d seems unsuitable.

Does anyone know any package that can solve it?